# Ubuntu 14.04 locks screen without dimming during fullscreen video playing?

Tags: video, screen, brightness, fullscreen

I upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 yesterday, and it appears that something has changed concerning how screen dimming works during fullscreen video playback.

This problem does not occur during video playback from my HDD, as the computer does not lock itself while I am doing that.  This issue only occurs when streaming videos over the Internet.  Formerly, in 13.10, the screen would dim, which was a good warning for when I needed to remind the computer I'm still there.  However, the screen no longer does this.  Instead, it immediately locks itself at the predetermined time.

The screen dims normally when I am not watching a video fullscreen.  Is this an issue new to 14.04 or is it something I switched in my computer somewhere?  I checked the settings, and the dim screen option is still on.

Thank you for any assistance.  I realize that I can just set the computer not to lock itself, but I'd have to set it for half an hour, and I don't want to forget I did so, and leave the computer vulnerable that long.

Answer (score 0):

The package Caffeine solves this exact problem.

It installs an indicator at the top right portion of the top menu, where time and battery is located. And you can enable it before playing full screen videos and during that time, it will not dim. After watching the movie or video, disable it again, to get the dimming functionality back.

In order to install Caffeine:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

It will start automatically after rebooting the machine, or start it from your dash.